# Compactification of Polish space , What is its use?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to know the use of the fact that a Polish space can be homeomorphically embedded into a dense subset of a compact metric space.

For example, a continuous function $f$ on a Polish space can't be thought as the continuous function on the compact space because that requires a continuous extrension of the function $f\circ\phi^{-1}$. $\phi$ is the homeomorphism.

In other words, is Polish space with compactification a replacement for compact space ?

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/206437/21564).